# javax.imageio.IIOException When reading the Input File

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon, javax.imageio

I am trying to set Image to a JLabel. I used this code, And it works fine in the IDE. But when I try to run Executable Jar file in dist folder It gives me this error.

> javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!

How to fix that issue. 
Please anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

**Code is,**

```
ImageIcon iconPicture = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("./src/PIC/Images/profileImage.png")));
pictureLabel.setIcon(iconPicture);
```

Comment: Try using absolute path or fix the relative path of image file.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I didn't understand that.

Comment: in .jar file it does not include `src` folder, thats why it doesnt work

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana: my explanation wouldn't fit in a comment so I have tried explaining in my answer.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Since the image is stored with the `src` folder, it should be treated as an embedded resource. While using an absolute path "might" fix the problem immediately, it won't solve the problem in the long run or when the execution location changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why this GUI app does not show me the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160543/why-this-gui-app-does-not-show-me-the-image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't rely on the "working directory" been the same as the location where the Jar/classes are stored.

```
ImageIcon iconPicture = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("./src/PIC/Images/profileImage.png")));
```

This suggests to me that you are dealing with an embedded resource, one which is contained within the classpath/Jar file.  In this case, you should be loading the resource using `Class#getResource` instead, as the resource won't be readable as a `File` (if it's contained in the Jar file).

So, instead of the above, you should be doing something more like...

```
ImageIcon iconPicture = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/PIC/Images/profileImage.png")));
```

Comment: i can't write this code ImageIcon iconPicture = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/PIC/Images/profileImage.png")));

because I am writing that code in a separate static class. it get error when writing getClass()

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana in that case use, `ClassName.class.getResource()`

Comment:  - Then use `WhatEverYouClassNameIsBecauseYouveNotProvidedItInYourExampleSoIDontKnow.class.getResource(...)` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer It worked very well. Thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 2):

Your program when run is not able to find image from your given path

```
./src/PIC/Images/profileImage.png
```

Here . refers to current directory and when you must be running your program, . must not be what you intend it to be. So one way to fix the problem is to either use absolute path, which would be something like

```
D:/work/proj1/src/PIC/Images/profileImage.png
```

Or

You need to find the current dir as per your project and then construct the correct relative path.

You can find current dir path with following one liner code,

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
```

Find your current path and then correct the relative path of image that you have given.